# Trigger event when app is installed/uninstalled Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to get some information (date,etc) when an app is installed/uninstalled, I have found some useful posts about how to achieve this with ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED & ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED intents,but even with this I can not get the correct approach ... any help will be appreciated. Thanks.
This is the a simple code i wr

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
```

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public MyReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    Log.d("Receiver", "Intent: " + intent.getAction());
}
```

}

Comment: show your incorrect code then

Comment: What do you want to do? The broadcasts do work for me. What doesnt work for you?

Comment: I am sure it does, the thing is i want to do that but for my own application..    this is the code i have right now ..

Comment: So in fact you did nothing. what is your question then?

Comment: The question is ... how I can trigger the install/uninstall event for my own application? , because i need to register some information like installation date for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove

```
<data android:scheme="package" />
```

from your `<intent-filter>`

**EDIT**

> The question is ... how I can trigger the install/uninstall event for my own application?

You will not get information related to your own package.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround you can use to track updates for your own app.

1. Implement a dummy database  and override *SQLiteOpenHelper.html* ***onUpgrade()***.The onUpgrade() method is called whenever a new database version is installed.For more info-[refer here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29)
2. Now everytime you have a new update for an app..update the database version too.In this way you will have one to one mapping between database version and the app version.
3. Now when the user updates the app ***onUpgrade()*** is called and you can write whatever logic you want to track the update.(If you are using database in your app, you might need some extra logic to differentiate between actual database upgrade and app upgrade.)